# How to do mission 'The Molecular Level' with Brotherhood of Steel?

Tags: fallout-4

I am having hard time powering up Teleporter when aligning myself with Brotherhood of steel.

**I don't get additional items required in special build menu, what do I do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it took me quite some reading and researching to do this one, as it is counter-intuitive.

First you need to build teleporter, then run back to the Scribe and she gives you extra items that you need to power it up to appear in you build special menu.

Then you can't just power them up, which I have ofc messed up first time I did this, you need to build a pylon and 3 large generators connect all of them to pylon and then connect wires from pylon to devises built.

Comment: I linked several questions here as duplicates earlier. Most of them don't have good details on where exactly things break down, to the point they may just be doing it wrong. This is a correct way to do it that should work for everybody, substituting whichever faction engineer they're working with for Ingram. If somebody has their question closed as a duplicate of this and finds it unhelpful, they are asked to please edit their question to elaborate on that.