# Fallout 4: The Molecular Level Bug

Tags: fallout-4

I've just started The Molecular Level mission and I chose to go through the BoS.
I just built the stabilized reflector platform, but it doesn't show it as built. It still has the hovering marker above the workshop. I went to try to talk to Proctor Ingram and she just gave me her generic responses. I really don't want to go back to my last save because it's an entire 5-6 hours behind back at the Cambridge Police Station when the Prydwen first arrives. If anyone has any fixes for this, that would be awesome.

Comment: I've looked into that thread and even though that is similar, he's under different circumstances. I'm unable to build anything at all after the stabilized reflector platform. Ingram won't give me another items list. She just gives me generic responses.

Comment: if you think your question is different enough to not be a duplicate, I would suggest adding more detail. The problem you are encountering sounds almost identical to the bug being encountered in the dupe. In fact, I would say it is the exact same bug, you might just be having a differant issue, as a result. You definetly want to make your question more clear.

Comment: For example, ***your not actually asking a question***. Do you want to reset the quest without resetting your overall progress? Do you want to know *why* your platform is not showing as complete? Do you want to know if there is a work around? What your asking might seem obvious to you, but different users have different interpretations.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I'm on Xbox One, just for more information. I was wondering if there was a way around this issue or if I'm going to have to just go back to the old save.

Comment: Can you store or scrap the platform you built? Can you build another one, at the same location or a different one? Where are you trying to build it?

Comment: I voted to reopen because the other question has encountered an issue at a different point. They're on the next objective, after trying to build the other components. This asker hasn't got the blueprints for the other components yet. Could still use more details, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do mission 'The Molecular Level' with Brotherhood of Steel?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244443/how-to-do-mission-the-molecular-level-with-brotherhood-of-steel)

Answer (score 2):

## Your structure is not built properly.

The first piece is the Stabilized Reflector Platform.  After that piece is built, you will then finish the rest of it and the Beam Emitter is suppose to snap on top of the Platform.  However, it is possible the platform is sunk into the ground and the Beam Emitter does not snap to it.

You need to store the Platform, build a wooden floor, build put the Platform on the wooden floor, then try snapping the Beam Emitter on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try building all of the Signal Interceptor and wiring it up. I had the same issue but once I had it all set up the mission continued.

Comment: That's the issue. I've been given the parts list for the reflector platform so I went to the workbench at the airport and built that. I've gotten rid of the carpets and everything like that, but after I placed the platform, it doesn't give me a confirmation that it has been built. I go to talk to the proctor and she keeps giving me responses on power armor. Not giving me the next list.

Comment: You should've gotten it all. Have you tried building the rest of it?

Comment: The problem is that if the Proctor doesn't give the list for the rest of the items needed to form the entire device they can't be built. I'm attempting to deal with the same bug in my present game. I'm building on a concrete surface. Does anyone have a way to solve the problem?